# What are you maximizing when you maximize the determinant of $A^TA$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m$ by $n$ $(0,1)$-matrix with $m < n$.  If we maximize $\operatorname{det}(AA^T)$ then what property of $A$ are we optimizing?

This isn't simply maximizing the rank of $A$ and nor is it exactly ensuring that the rows of $A$ are orthogonal.

**July 9 2015**

Fixed typo and changed  $A^TA$ to $AA^T$ in question.

Comment: This is the volume, isn't it?

Comment: Did you mean $m>n$? With $m<n$, $\det(A^TA)=0$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It was a typo, thank you. I meant $AA^T$.

Comment: @YoavKallus It seems I can't delete the question so can it be migrated to math.stackexchange?

Comment: Since you insist that $A$ is a $\{0,1\}$-matrix, you know that ${\rm tr}(AA^{T})$ is just the sum of the entries of $A$. Assuming that $AA^{T}$ is non-singular (equivalently, $A$ has rank at least $m$), we have ${\rm det}(A A^{T}) \leq \left( \frac{{\rm Tr}(AA^{T})}{m} \right)^{m}$ by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, and (since $AA^{T}$ is diagonalizable), equality only occurs when $AA^{T}$ is a scalar matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course if $A$ is $m$ by $m$ then this is the square of $det (A)$, so the square of the factor by which $A:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m$ multiplies $m$-dimensional volume.

More generally if $A$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$ with $m\le n$, viewed as a map to an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, then it is still the square of the factor by which $A$ multiplies $m$-dimensional volume.

Comment: Is maximizing the $m$-dimensional volume essentially the same as ensuring that the rows of $A$ are maximally orthogonal?